# How to use SUMIF combined with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup, sumifs

I have column A with these numbers:

```
 £ 2,495.19 
 £ 2,450.02 
 £ 3,162.53 
 £ 3,097.03 
 £ -   
 £ 2,043.52 
 £ -   
 £ 3,490.03 
 £ -   

 £ -
```

And then another table with these numbers:

```
£3,271.70   £2,561.63
£3,642.87   £3,607.13
£2,495.19   £1,504.81
£2,450.02   £1,466.65
£3,162.53   £2,254.13
£3,097.03   £2,069.63
£2,043.52   £1,123.15
£3,162.53   £2,254.13
£3,490.03   £3,176.63
£3,599.20   £3,484.13
£3,490.03   £3,176.63
£3,708.37   £3,791.63
£3,490.03   £3,176.63
£3,380.87   £2,869.13
£2,133.85   £1,199.48
£2,359.69   £1,390.31
£3,490.03   £3,176.63
£3,490.03   £3,176.63
£3,053.37   £1,946.63
£2,133.85   £1,199.48
```

What I want to do is to add a sum figure at the bottom of column A, which checks if the figure is on the LHS of the second table, and if its there, adds what is to the right of it.

So in this case it would be £1,504.81 + £1,466.65 + £2,254.13 etc.

I don't want to add another column essentially to column A to do the VLOOKUP, and then have to do the SUMIF.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I don't want to add another column essentially to column A to do the VLOOKUP, and then have to do the SUMIF

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIF`

```
=SUM(SUMIF(currTbl[LHS],A1:A10,currTbl[RHS]))
```

I used a table and structured references for `range` and `sum_range` arguments, but you could substitute the appropriate range references if you prefer not to use a table.

Note that since the criteria argument is an array, the `SUMIF` function will return an array of values.  Hence the formula needs to be "wrapped" in the `SUM` function and entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

To do this without the CSE, you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(currTbl[LHS],A1:A10,currTbl[RHS]))
```